# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary' switft 5

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I want to get list of users from Firebase database and put that in a Users array but I am unable to get data from the snapshot

This is what I have tried

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}

 var users : [User] = []

  func fetchUsers() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            for child in (snapshot.children) {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let dic = snap.value as! [String: String] // erros here
                //print((dic["name"]))

                //WANT TO LOAD THE LIST OF USERS INTO `var users`
            }
        }
    }
```

Error
`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'`

This is how my data looks like on firebase database

[image]

Thanks for your help
R

Comment: please print child first ... and let me know what you got

Comment: hi Jawed thank  you for replying, i printed child and this is what i get Snap (email) Sairam11@gmail.com
Snap (name) Sairam11
Snap (email) Sairam2@gmail.com
Snap (name) Sairam 2
Snap (email) Sairam3@gmail.com
Snap (name) Sairam3
Snap (email) Sairam1@gmail.com
Snap (name) Sairam

Comment: what is DataSnapshot ? in which you are casting it forcefully ?

Comment: to be honest, I am pretty. new to swift and ios, so I am still learning, if DataSnapshot is not required. then could you let me know how to do it please

Comment: remove this line ... `let snap = child as! DataSnapshot`

Comment: add this ... `let dic = child.value as! [String: String]`

Comment: or `let dic = child.value as? NSDictionary` then `let username = dic?["name"] as? String ?? ""`

Comment: i get this error for  `child.value` `Value of type 'NSEnumerator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'value'`

Answer (score 0):

```
func fetchUsers() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                print(child.value)

               if let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let email = dict["email"] {
                      print(email)

                  }

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: let me know if it works ... if not .. then error and ... `print(child.value)` this print statement result

Comment: Hi I get the `child.value` as `Optinonal (Sairam11@gmail.com)` and so on and for `print(dict["name"])` i get `nil` here is the full output `Optional(Sairam11@gmail.com)
nil
Optional(Sairam11)
nil
Optional(Sairam2@gmail.com)
nil
Optional(Sairam 2)
nil
Optional(Sairam3@gmail.com)
nil
Optional(Sairam3)
nil
Optional(Sairam1@gmail.com)
nil
Optional(Sairam)
nil
`

Comment: check it out now brother

Comment: Hello brother, i tried that and I get this error on `let` - `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : AnyObject]'`

Comment: sorry .. my fault

Answer (score 0):

That's because `DataSnapshot` is a **String** to **Object** dictionary. This should do the trick

```
guard let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] 
else { 
   print("couldn't cast to dictionary")
   return 
}
print("successfully cast to dictionary")
print(dict["name"])
print(dict["email"])
```